# can PHP act as specific IP with proxy?

Tags: php, proxy

Is there any way that I can run a php (I have access to that) and the php grabs my ip and fetch something from another site pretending to be me(by proxy-ing my ip to remote location)?

Say my ip is : 192.353.89.xx
My server php grabs my ip when I execute it.
Then it fetches something from a remote site with my ip and processes and echos to me so that the remote server thinks its me pulling the info..

any ideas guys?

Comment: You can proxy with PHP but it will not grab your IP, it will use the server's IP. IP spoofing like this is thankfully no longer possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cannot be done using PHP. 
You can make the server fetch the page from the remote endpoint (using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)), but **not** [spoof your IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing).

Comment: ok..thanks for the response :D